# How to Animate Active Tabs

Tags: javascript, html, css

how does one animate tabs so like when you click the tab it slides in

i've tried the transition code

here's what i have so far

```
        [data-tab-info] {
            display: none;
        }

        .active[data-tab-info] {
            display: block;
        }

        .tab-content {
            font-size: 30px;
            font-family: sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .tabs {
            font-size: 40px;
            color: black;
            display: flex;
            margin: 30px;
        }

            .tabs span {
                transition: 0.3s linear;
                background: darkred;
                padding: 10px;
                border: 5px groove gray;
                border-radius: 5px;
            }

                .tabs span:hover {
                    background: firebrick;
                    cursor: url(https://cur.cursors-4u.net/cursors/cur-3/cur283.ani), url(http://www.rw-designer.com/cursor-download.php?id=58443), auto !important;
                    color: black;
                }
```

thanks, in advance

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Please be more specific, and share your HTML code too to provide a [mcve].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Use :action instead of :hover for action on click. Within that you can set the actions you want to happen on click.